# Improve search performance in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsstring

I am searching through around 100k strings in a function:

```
results = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int n = 0; n < (int)_donkey.searchStrings.count; n++){
    if ([[_donkey.searchStrings[n] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:tf.text.lowercaseString].location != NSNotFound){
        [results addObject:_donkey.formattedStrings[n]];
    }
}
```

where `tf.text` is the user inputted text in a `UITextField`. Performance is slow and I get the impression there is a better way of searching rather than a straight up string comparison anyway.

The strings being searched through are formatted like this: "attributeA attributeB attributeC", so if attributeB is entered before attributeA, it does not come up as a result, which it should.

Comment: Maybe you can do this with `NSPredicate` and/or `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: @Koen Both of those will be much slower than purposefully written code.

Comment: Unrelated to your performance issue but do not use `int` in your loop. `count` returns `NSUInteger`. The array access uses `NSUInteger`. So use `NSUInteger` for the loop variable (and get rid of the cast).

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, for some (non-logical) reason I prefer ints, but should learn to let go of bad coding habits :)

Answer (score 2):

A few obvious things:

- Don't call the `searchStrings` property getter multiple times through the loop. Call it once and cache it in a local variable.
- Don't call the `count` getter on every loop iteration.
- Don't call the `text` getter on every loop iteration.
- If you're going to use `lowercaseString`, don't call it on the text field's string on every loop iteration. But see the next item.
- Don't use `lowercaseString`. Use `-rangeOfString:options:` and the `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` option, `-localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:`, or `-localizedStandardContainsString:`. Not only are they likely to be faster, they're more correct. (Languages can be strange and comparing lowercased strings may not necessarily be the same as a case-insensitive comparison.)
- Since you're building an array from the indexes of the matching elements of `searchStrings`, you can use `-indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest:` to build a set of the indexes of the matching elements. You don't have to write the (slower) enumeration code yourself in that case. You can also specify `NSEnumerationConcurrent` in the options to allow the framework to use multiple threads to perform the search. After you have the index set, you would then use `-objectsAtIndexes:` to get an array of the corresponding elements from `formattedStrings`. Again, the framework can do that faster than your approach of building it up one element at a time in a mutable array. (Thanks to @rmaddy for the suggestion.)

> The strings being searched through are formatted like this: "attributeA attributeB attributeC", so if attributeB is entered before attributeA, it does not come up as a result, which it should.

I don't understand this part of your question and it seems like it's about correctness and not performance. So: 1) get correctness first before being concerned about performance. No point making a wrong algorithm faster. 2) It should be a separate question.

Comment: One more obvious suggestion - replace the slow C-style `for` loop with at least a `for in` loop but better yet, use `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:` possibly using the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, although that conflicts with the sorted array optimization. And, since he's constructing a new array, he could use `-indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:passingTest:` instead, followed by `-objectsAtIndexes:`. That, too, would probably be faster than element-by-element accumulation of the result array.

Comment: I meant to comment on your suggestion about sorting. That doesn't seem to apply in this case since the goal is to find every string in the list that contains the search text. Sorting won't help such a search. If the goal was to perform a prefix search, then a sort would be useful.

Comment: Ah, true. Edited to remove that.